# curl Request with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, curl, web, httpwebrequest

I have read some other posts on Stack but I can't get this to work. It works fine on my when I run the curl command in git on my windows machine but when I convert it to asp.net it's not working:

```
 private void BeeBoleRequest()
    {   
        string url = "https://mycompany.beebole-apps.com/api";

        WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);            

        string username = "e26f3a722f46996d77dd78c5dbe82f15298a6385";
        string password = "x";
        string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
        CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
        mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
        myReq.Credentials = mycache;
        myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

        WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Response.Write(content);
    }
```

This is the BeeBole API. Its pretty straight fwd. http://beebole.com/api but I am getting a following 500 error when I run the above:

The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The default HTTP method for WebRequest is GET. Try setting it to POST, as that's what the API is expecting

```
myReq.Method = "POST";
```

I assume you are posting something. As a test, I'm going to post the same data from their curl example.

```
string url = "https://YOUR_COMPANY_HERE.beebole-apps.com/api";
string data = "{\"service\":\"absence.list\", \"company_id\":3}";

WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
myReq.Method = "POST";
myReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
myReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

string usernamePassword = "YOUR API TOKEN HERE" + ":" + "x";

UTF8Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding();

myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(enc.GetBytes(usernamePassword)));


using (Stream ds = myReq.GetRequestStream())
{
ds.Write(enc.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length); 
}


WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
Response.Write(content);
```

Comment: not working when string data is thai langues
"{\"service\":\"ทดสอบ\", \"company_id\":3}"