# Sending Login info to a separate website

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I need to know if its possible to login to a website i am hosting that is asp.net mvc and on that login call a separate website function that is in php.

Also if it is possible how can I do it.

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Just make sure you're protected across CSRF attacks pretty darned well.

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544389/how-to-share-sessions-between-php-and-asp-net-application

Comment: It is possible using cross-site posting but I highly recommend not to do it. You need to let the second site accept cross-site posting, that brings a high risk of XSS-attack(cross site scripting).

Comment: I don't know much about ASP.net, however if I were doing this in PHP, I'd use cURL to talk to the other server.  I looked around SO for ASP.net versions of cURL and found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619065/curl-request-with-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, you have to post to the login page.
So if you use php use [cUrl](https://php.net/curl) and set post option and values. 
After the login i guess you want to do more? So you will need to save the session, so you can send that for the next requests as logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass any kind of data around the web using (typically) GET or POST http requests. (There are others of course, but these two are the most typically used). In terms of login / user authentication, a commonly accepted standard to use is [oAuth](http://oauth.net/). No doubt there are libraries which help support the use of oAuth in both PHP and ASP.

Essentially, the programming language is irrelevant, as data is passed around on the other end of the application layer. The way you access this data may differ from language to language, but the transport method is usually always the same.

As an example, GET data is passed around in the URL:

```
location.com/?myparam=myvalue
```

**A word of warning:** You should **always** be using **https** when handling personal / sensitive data. Generally, both the sending and receiving devices should be doing so over **https** with a valid SSL license. This prevents third party data sniffing and most man in the middle attacks.

As for libraries which send requests, well php has [cURL](https://php.net/curl) and asp.net has [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)