# Still no solution how to simple post a Facebook wall

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to post a message from my personal website to the website´s facebook wall page. **I dont want the user to authenticate against facebook**, instead a default website account should be used(probably the facebook app).

This is what I have :

1. Created facebook App at https://developers.facebook.com
2. Add [Facebook.dll](http://facebookapi.codeplex.com/releases/view/76672) to my ASP.NET webform site(the personal site)
3. Included the following code :

   FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient();

   ```
   result = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
   {
       client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
       client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
       grant_type = "client_credentials"
   });
   client.AccessToken = result.access_token;

   result = client.Post("1418771281723422/feed", new { message = "Test Message from app" });
   result = client.Get("1418771281723422");
   ```

This returns the following exception on client.Post

> A first chance exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException'
>   occurred in Facebook.dll
>
> Additional information: (OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't
>   authorized the application to perform this action

What am I doing wrong and why is it so hard to do this simple task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to authorize a User to post on Facebook - else it would be incredibly easy to create a spam App.

What you need is a Page Access Token, take a look at the Facebook docs about the different Tokens and how to get them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

More information about Access Tokens: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

The code is in PHP, but the text is valid for every language anyway.

This is how to generate an Extended Page Token with PHP: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

An Extended Page Token may be exactly what you need, it is valid forever and you can post "as Page" with it.

Doing this with ASP.NET should be pretty similar, but you don´t really need that Facebook SDK if you take a look at the tutorial for extending a Page Token with CURL. This question may help you: [curl Request with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619065/curl-request-with-asp-net)

To create an Extended Page Token only for yourself, i suggest creating it without any coding:

- Use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to create a User Access Token with your App.
- Extend the User Access Token: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=[app-id]&client_secret=[app-secret]&fb_exchange_token=[short-lived-token]
- Put that resulting User Token in the "Access Token" field of the Graph API Explorer
- Make a call to /me/accounts to get a list of all your Facebook Pages
- Take the Access Token of your Page and use it in a server side call for posting

It´s explained in this article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: But I thought that a facebook app created at the developer page could act as the webpage user? What I need to do is that when a user post a post on the website1 I need the website1 to forward this post(with the website1 as the author(not the user)) to the website1´s facebook wall. So the regular facebook user do not really have much to do with it more then writing the text.

Comment: no, that is not how it works. as i said, you ALWAYS need authorization to post something on facebook.

Comment: get familiar with the existing access token, they are very important.

Comment: So, I could not even use my own(static) facebook user to post from my website up to the facebook wall when another member of my webpage makes a post on the regular webpage?

Comment: Let me be more clear. I got a webpage with members, when a member post in a specific forum I want to let the webpage itself post this message on the website´s facebook wall. I could to it manully with my own user but I need to to be automatic and when another user is posting on my webpage.

Comment: for that, the best solution is to use an extended page access token, as i posted. you can also use a user access token, but that one is valid for 60 days max so you have to refresh it every 2 months. but this is weird anyway, why would you post something from another person on facebook even with a page token? (meaning, "as page") - with your own user account? (which is even worse)

Comment: What I need is to post all buy/sell ads posted on my webpage direcly on to the website´s facebook wall. This will make it easier for facebook users to follow when there is new ads posted to my site.

Comment: Its is App Access Token I have looked into before, are you sure that this is not the one I should use? And if so, why?

Comment: app access tokens are not for publishing (well, they CAN be used to publish open graph actions), they are for reading public stuff and changing app settings.

Comment: anyway, for what you want to achieve, the only serious way is to use a page acces token and post "as page" on the page wall. check out my answer, it includes all the code you need.

Comment: Thanks, I do however not understand the PHP part.

Comment: it should be pretty similar with ASP.NET, i guess. i will add a link to my answer that may help you.

Comment: Thanks, so what I need to do is, 1. Get the Facebook SDK JAVA and include it in my probject, 2. Creat a ASPX(HTML) that runnes the FB.login at $(document ).ready() and also references the Facebook SDK JAva, 3. Add codebehind code for the ASPX webpage that will do the webrequest part and this is to be done at PageLoad(before the HTML is generated and sent to user). Is this correct?

Comment: javascript, not java. there is a VERY big difference. just saying ;)

Comment: not sure why $(document).ready though. juery is not neccessary, just use the async function from the javascript sdk.

Comment: i´ve also added a step by step tutorial how to create an extended page token without programming. a lot easier like that, you only need to hardcode that page token in your server side code for feed posting.