# How to integrate the codes which instagram provides?

Tags: asp.net, instagram, integrate

You know, instagram provides lots of codes for developers for example : **https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN**

I have figured how to get access token out but How can I integrate those codes to fetch info from instagram with asp.net?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

After you get the access token, you will need to have a `cURL` call to that API endpoint. on ASP it will be handled by `WebRequest` object. I'm not good at ASP, but [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619065/curl-request-with-asp-net) should give you some information on how to call and handle the response of the API data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=" + your_access_token;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var jsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```