# Convert curl code to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, asp.net-ajax

I am writing some code to update Credit Card details for Credit Cards that are stored on Stripe in a MVC 5 view.

Here is an api reference:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#update_card

The reference is using curl. Am I correct in saying that I can make an ajax call to the curl url and it will achieve the same result as using curl?

May I have some help to convert the curl code into an ajax call?

Here is the curl code:

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/{CUSTOMER_ID}/cards/{CARD_ID}

curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_5iRk16Lkf8knHW/cards/card_15X158B0kSXRxQJDzHdigbYq \
   -u sk_test_Z8pMCKSd34P8XLzrcbumkGZo: \
   -d name="Jane Austen"
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
function testAjaxFunction()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_5iSot8lwZQS8ra/cards/card_15X1t6B0kSXRxQJDKmdGdLTC',
        data: {
            'name': "Jane Austen"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error");
            alert(data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

This code above returns an error.

What does the `-u sk_test_Z8pMCKSd34P8XLzrcbumkGZo: \` need to be coded to for the ajax request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work with an AJAX call alone. Replace `alert("error");` with `alert(data.statusText);` and you'll see it was blocked by cross-domain policy. If you have this working from your server via curl, you can create an API for yourself to make AJAX calls to. The API would be a web interface to your curl call, and you could POST your AJAX calls to it. Your AJAX call would look more like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: '/api/stripe/',
    data: {
        'name': "Jane Austen",
        'customer_id': "cus_5iSot8lwZQS8ra",
        'card_id': "card_15X1t6B0kSXRxQJDKmdGdLTC"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not have this working via curl. I am deciding the best way to update credit card details. I have never used curl before.

Comment: I'd suggest that the best way would be to handle it from the server. The example you posted is CLI curl, but you can also make a curl call from asp.net. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619065/curl-request-with-asp-net