# how to add server side validation to a 3rd party supplied html form (post method)

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a form that was supplied by a third party to put onto a registration page. It works fine, but it looks very susceptible to a bot to send spam. I am trying to add a captcha but the form is posting before my validation fires. This is on an asp.net web form C# 4.0.

The form looks like this

```
<form method="post" name="upsideContactUsForm-1343676638998" action="https://3rdPartySite" id="form173" runat="server">
<input id="field0" value="" type="text" name="email" />
<!--  ..Other fields like first name, last name, etc -->

<input type="submit", value="submit"></input>

<script src="https://3rdPartySiteValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var field0 = new LiveValidation("field0", { validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: true });
    field0.add(Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: "This field is required" });
    field0.add(Validate.Email, { failureMessage: "Please enter a valid email address" }); 
    //..Validation rules for the fields
</script>
</form>
```

I replaced the submit button with an asp:button and adding a captcha with a warning label. I am checking server side like this to see if I could prevent the page from firing but no luck.

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    CaptchaMsg.Text = "Your response is correct!";
}
else
{
    CaptchaMsg.Text = "Your response is incorrect!";

}
```

}

Clicking the submit button with nothing in the captcha makes the form post and I am redirected to the page set in the form action. This is kind of what I expected would happen as I am posting a form, but I am not sure what direction to take to get around this. I could add a pass-through page that they are initially redirected to, but that seems sloppy. I also looked at answering my captcha with ajax, but that doesn't work if javascript is disabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this what I am looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258864/redirect-to-another-page-using-post-method-from-code-behind

Comment: Or trapping the form's onsubmit event with a javascript solution. Changing from post to get as in the post you found won't do anything to make the catchpa run. If js is disabled the code you've got posted won't work anyway.