# asp.net button onclick post to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, postback

I have a page in .Net that currently does some processing of info when a button is clicked. It posts back, updates some info and then redirects the user onwards.

What I want to do now is for this same button, when it's clicked, the info is updated but instead of a redirect it does a POST to another site. The reason being that this other site needs to read a bunch of data from the form I submit.

So, I know about the PostBackUrl property but that will stop the processing of the data that I need done.

So is there another way for me to be able to somehow combine both a postback that then becomes as POST to another site?

Or alternatively some way for me to be able to do the updates I need and then do a POST?

Comment: In the end this was the only solution that worked for me:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2802848/989348

Comment: Marked for some reason as a 'trivial answer'. Odd, seeing as it is a working answer. Maybe I should have copied and pasted it here or waffled on for a few pages so that it wouldn't be considered trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solutions all kind-of worked but the only one that actually did exactly what I needed it to was this one:

[Link to SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get/2802848#2802848)

The reason the other answers above didn't work is that I was POSTing to a payment gateway and for whatever reason their system thought there was a problem with various missing fields in all solutions except the one I linked to. No idea why, I don't have access to their systems to know what they were actually doing.

In any case, thanks for all answers but have a look at the linked one if you're running into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

if PostBack isn't absolutely needed, you can actually send them in the request query itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `POST` from codebehind, you can find details in this answer [Redirect to another page using Post method from Code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258864/redirect-to-another-page-using-post-method-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right I think you will need to get all the form data from Request.Form and make a HttpWebRequest to the other site:

```
string url = "http://anothersite.com/";

// create post data
StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var key in this.Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    postDataBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", this.Request.Form[key]);
}

string postData = postDataBuilder.ToString();

// create the web request for the POST
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

// add the post data
using (StreamWriter requestStream = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    requestStream.Write(postData);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THanks, tried that but the site that I'm posting to is giving an error. Not sure why yet.

Comment: I think it's a specific error to the payment gateway that I'm trying to post to. Basically it's saying one of the fields is empty or malformed - it isn't. I've sent them the example and they can find nothing wrong with it. I have to presume it's down to use the above method rather than a normal form POST.