# Redirecting to AND posting data to an external page

Tags: c#, .net, jquery

I have a search page on my .NET 3.5 Web Forms site that redirects a user to an external site based on the user's search parameters. I would redirect to: http://www.site.com/search.aspx?searchterm=Hello.

But now they are changing the site so that the search parameter is passed as a POST parameter, and not in the query string. So the page is expecting "searchterm".

So not only do I need to redirect to the external page, I have to post data to the page as well. I have no idea how to do this and I don't know where to start.

Is this something I can do in Web Forms without some glitchy workaround? Or maybe it can be done using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers will explicitely deny this. Doing a cross server post like this would lead to security issues.

Comment: Well how about if it's on the same server?

Comment: You would still need to do this from the client side. Just change the form action to point to the desired URL instead of doing the server side redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple JavaScript function for execute POST redirect to external page (dynamicaly generate and initilaze form object and submit it).
For example (values pattern: a=1&b=2&c=3 ...):

```
function bind(pageURL, values) {
var form=document.createElement('form');
form.action= pageURL;
form.target='_blank';
form.style.display = 'none';
form.method = 'POST';

var valuesSplit = node.get_value().toString().split("&");

    for (var i = 0; i < valuesSplit.length - 1; i++) {
        var p = valuesSplit[i];
        var ps = p.split('=');
        addParam(form, ps[0], ps[1]);
    }

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}

function addParam(form,key,value){
  var input= document.createElement('input');
  input.name=key;
  input.value=value;
  form.appendChild(input);
}
```