# IPN can't be tested through Paypal test tool (HTTP error code 500) _ Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-ipn

Good day
I have been trying to run an IPN Handler for PayPal; I have followed all possible instructions (I hope), however on paypal IPN testing tool I keep on receiving an error of code 500. 
The code I have utilized is the one provided as an opensource by johnmendez00; the class is called by creating an instance as

```
PPIPN objPP = new PPIPN("TEST");
objPP.FromEmail = "email@yourdomain.com";  
objPP.FromEmailPassword = "yourpassword";  
objPP.SmtpHost = "yourSMTPHost";
objPP.SmtpPort = "SMTPHostPort";
objPP.ToEmail = "youremailatPayPal@domain.com";/ 
objPP.MakeHttpPost();
objPP.CheckStatus();
```

the class of the instance is as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Project can be found in http://paypalipnclass.codeplex.com/
/// </summary>



using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
public class PPIPN
 {

string _txnID, _txnType, _paymentStatus, _receiverEmail, _itemName, _itemNumber, _quantity, _invoice, _custom,
_paymentGross, _payerEmail, _pendingReason, _paymentDate, _paymentFee, _firstName, _lastName, _address,
_city, _state, _zip, _country, _countryCode, _addressStatus, _payerStatus, _payerID, _paymentType, _notifyVersion,
_verifySign, _response, _payerPhone, _payerBusinessName, _business, _receiverID, _memo, _tax, _qtyCartItems,
_shippingMethod, _shipping;

private string _postUrl = "";
private string _strRequest = "";
private string _smtpHost, _fromEmail, _toEmail, _fromEmailPassword, _smtpPort;

/// <summary>
/// valid strings are "TEST" for sandbox use 
/// "LIVE" for production use
/// "ELITE" for test use off of PayPal...avoid having to be logged into PayPal Developer
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mode"></param>
public PPIPN(string mode)
{
    if (mode.ToLower() == "test")
        this.PostUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    else if (mode.ToLower() == "live")
        this.PostUrl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    else if (mode.ToLower() == "elite")
        this.PostUrl = "http://www.eliteweaver.co.uk/testing/ipntest.php";
    else
        this.PostUrl = "";

    //this.fillProperties();
}

#region "Properties"

private string PostUrl
{
    get { return _postUrl; }
    set { _postUrl = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the reponse back from the http post back to PayPal.
/// Possible values are "VERIFIED" or "INVALID"
/// </summary>
private string Response
{
    get { return _response; }
    set { _response = value; }
}

private string RequestLength
{
    get { return _strRequest; }
    set { _strRequest = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Provide your outgoing email server to use are your SMTP host
/// </summary>
public string SmtpHost
{
    get { return _smtpHost; }
    set { _smtpHost = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Provide the port your outgoing SMTP host uses
/// </summary>
public string SmtpPort
{
    get { return _smtpPort; }
    set { _smtpPort = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the email address that will show to the customer and you. This most likely
/// needs to be a valid email address that your SMTP server will accept
/// Examples would be something like no-reply@yourdomain.com
/// </summary>
public string FromEmail
{
    get { return _fromEmail; }
    set { _fromEmail = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the password that the FromEmail property will use. This needs to be the password
/// for the email account itself
/// </summary>
public string FromEmailPassword
{
    get { return _fromEmailPassword; }
    set { _fromEmailPassword = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the email address that you use for yourself. This should be set to
/// the email that is registered for your PayPal account.
/// </summary>
public string ToEmail
{
    get { return _toEmail; }
    set { _toEmail = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Email address or Account ID of the payment recipient.  This is equivalent
///  to the value of receiver_email if the payment is sent to the primary account
/// , which is most cases it is.  This value is that value of what is set in the button html
/// markup.  This value also get normalized to lowercase when coming back from PayPal
/// </summary>
private string Business
{
    get { return _business; }
    set { _business = value; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Unique transaction ID generated by PayPal. Helpful to use for checking
///  against fraud to make sure the transaction hasn't already occured.
/// </summary>
private string TXN_ID
{
    get { return _txnID; }
    set { _txnID = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Type of transaction from the customer. Possible values are
/// "cart", "express_checkout", "send_money", "virtual_terminal", "web-accept"
/// </summary>
private string TXN_Type
{
    get { return _txnType; }
    set { _txnType = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the status of the payment from the Customer.Possible values are: 
/// "Canceled_Reversal", "Completed", "Denied", "Expired", "Failed", "Pending",
///  "Processed", "Refunded", "Reversed", "Voided"
/// </summary>
private string PaymentStatus
{
    get { return _paymentStatus; }
    set { _paymentStatus = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Primary email address of you, the recipient, of the payment.
/// </summary>
private string ReceiverEmail
{
    get { return _receiverEmail; }
    set { _receiverEmail = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// unique account ID of the payment recipient, which is most likely yourself.
/// </summary>
private string ReceiverID
{
    get { return _receiverID; }
    set { _receiverID = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the item name passed by yourself or if the customer if you let them enter in an item name
/// </summary>
private string ItemName
{
    get { return _itemName; }
    set { _itemName = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the item number you set for your own tracking purposes. It is not required by PayPal
/// so if you didn't set it most likely will come back blank.
/// </summary>
private string ItemNumber
{
    get { return _itemNumber; }
    set { _itemNumber = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Quantity of the item ordered by the customer
/// </summary>
private string Quantity
{
    get { return _quantity; }
    set { _quantity = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Quantity of the items in the shopping cart from the Customer
/// </summary>
private string QuantityCartItems
{
    get { return _qtyCartItems; }
    set { _qtyCartItems = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoice number passed by yourself, if you didn't pass it to PayPal then this is omitted.
/// </summary>
private string Invoice
{
    get { return _invoice; }
    set { _invoice = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Custom value passed by yourself with the item.
/// </summary>
private string Custom
{
    get { return _custom; }
    set { _custom = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Memo entered in by the customer on PayPal website note field
/// </summary>
private string Memo
{
    get { return _memo; }
    set { _memo = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Amount of tax charged on the payment
/// </summary>
private string Tax
{
    get { return _tax; }
    set { _tax = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Full USD amount of customer's payment before the PayPal fee is subtracted
/// </summary>
private string PaymentGross
{
    get { return _paymentGross; }
    set { _paymentGross = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Date Time stamp created by PayPal in the following format: 
/// HH:MM:SS DD Mmm YY, YYYY PST
/// </summary>
private string PaymentDate
{
    get { return _paymentDate; }
    set { _paymentDate = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// PayPal's transaction fees associated with purchase.
/// </summary>
private string PaymentFee
{
    get { return _paymentFee; }
    set { _paymentFee = value; }
}


/// <summary>
/// This is the email that the customer used on PayPal or that
/// is registered with PayPal
/// </summary>
private string PayerEmail
{
    get { return _payerEmail; }
    set { _payerEmail = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's phone number
/// </summary>
private string PayerPhone
{
    get { return _payerPhone; }
    set { _payerPhone = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's company name if they represent a business
/// </summary>
private string PayerBusinessName
{
    get { return _payerBusinessName; }
    set { _payerBusinessName = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This variable is only set if the payment_status=Pending. Possible values are the following:
/// "address", "authorization", "echeck", "intl", "multi-currency", "unilateral", "upgrade",
///  "verify", other"
/// </summary>
private string PendingReason
{
    get { return _pendingReason; }
    set { _pendingReason = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is indicated from what is set in your PayPal profile settings
/// </summary>
private string ShippingMethod
{
    get { return _shippingMethod; }
    set { _shippingMethod = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Shipping charges associated with the order.
/// </summary>
private string Shipping
{
    get { return _shipping; }
    set { _shipping = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's First Name
/// </summary>
private string PayerFirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { _firstName = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's Last Name
/// </summary>
private string PayerLastName
{
    get { return _lastName; }
    set { _lastName = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's street address
/// </summary>
private string PayerAddress
{
    get { return _address; }
    set { _address = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's city
/// </summary>
private string PayerCity
{
    get { return _city; }
    set { _city = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer state of address
/// </summary>
private string PayerState
{
    get { return _state; }
    set { _state = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Zip code of customer's address
/// </summary>
private string PayerZipCode
{
    get { return _zip; }
    set { _zip = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's country
/// </summary>
private string PayerCountry
{
    get { return _country; }
    set { _country = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's 2 character country code
/// </summary>
private string PayerCountryCode
{
    get { return _countryCode; }
    set { _countryCode = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// The the address provided is either confirmed or uncomfirmed from PayaPal. Possible values  from PayPal
/// are going to be "confirmed" or "unconfirmed"
/// </summary>
private string PayerAddressStatus
{
    get { return _addressStatus; }
    set { _addressStatus = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer either had a verified or unverified account with PayPal. 
/// Possible return values from PayPal are "verified" or "unverified"
/// </summary>
private string PayerStatus
{
    get { return _payerStatus; }
    set { _payerStatus = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Customer's unique ID
/// </summary>
private string PayerID
{
    get { return _payerID; }
    set { _payerID = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Type of payment from Customer. Possible values from PayPal are "echeck" and "instant"
/// </summary>
private string PaymentType
{
    get { return _paymentType; }
    set { _paymentType = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the version number of the IPN that makes the post.
/// </summary>
private string NotifyVersion
{
    get { return _notifyVersion; }
    set { _notifyVersion = value; }
}

/// <summary>
/// An encrypted string that is used to validate the transaction. You don't have to use this for anything
///  unless you want to keep it and store it for your records.
/// </summary>
private string VerifySign
{
    get { return _verifySign; }
    set { _verifySign = value; }
}

#endregion

#region "Make HTTP POST"

/// <summary>
/// This makes the post back to PayPal to verify the order.
/// </summary>
public void MakeHttpPost()
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.PostUrl);

    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentLength = this.RequestLength.Length + 21;
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] param = HttpContext.Current.Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    this.RequestLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
    this.RequestLength += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
    req.ContentLength = this.RequestLength.Length;

    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(this.RequestLength);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    this.Response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();
}

#endregion

#region "Check Status of Order"

/// <summary>
/// This checks the status of the order and notifies you via email the status.
/// </summary>
public void CheckStatus()
{
    this.fillProperties();
    switch (this.Response)
    {
        case "VERIFIED":


            switch (this.PaymentStatus)
            {
                case "Completed": //If statement to check and verify the business email and that the script was triggered from the buy_now button.
                    if (this.ReceiverEmail == this.ToEmail)
                    {
                        switch (this.TXN_Type)
                        {
                            case "cart":
                                this.EmailUs("PayPal: Successful Order from Cart");
                                break;
                            case "express_checkout":
                                this.EmailUs("PayPal: Successful Order from Express Checkout");
                                break;
                            case "send_money":
                                this.EmailUs("PayPal: Successful Order from Send Money");
                                break;
                            case "virtual_terminal":
                                this.EmailUs("PayPal: Successful Order from Virtual Terminal");
                                break;
                            case "web_accept":
                                this.EmailUs("PayPal: Successful Order from Web_Accept");
                                break;
                            default:
                                this.EmailUs("PayPal: Order has been placed");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.EmailUs("PayPal: Unknown order...please check your paypal account");
                    }
                    break;
                case "Pending":
                    switch (this.PendingReason)
                    {
                        case "address":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of address");
                            break;
                        case "authorization":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of authorization");
                            break;
                        case "echeck":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of echeck");
                            break;
                        case "intl":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of non-US Acccount");
                            break;
                        case "multi-currency":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of multi-currency");
                            break;
                        case "unilateral":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of Unilateral");
                            break;
                        case "upgrade":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of Upgrade");
                            break;
                        case "verify":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of Verification needed");
                            break;
                        case "other":
                            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Pending Order because of other reason");
                            break;
                        default:
                            this.EmailUs(string.Format("PayPal: Pending Order because of unknown reason of {0}", this.PendingReason));
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Failed":
                    this.EmailUs("PayPal: Failed order");
                    break;
                case "Denied":
                    this.EmailUs("PayPal: Denied order");
                    break;
            }

            this.EmailBuyer("Order Received", "Your order has been received and will begin processing shortly.");

            break;
        case "INVALID":
            this.EmailUs("PayPal: Invalid order, please review and investigate");
            break;
        default:
            this.EmailUs("PayPal: ERROR, response is " + this.Response);
            break;
    }
}


#endregion

#region "Mail Company the Order"
/// <summary>
/// Email yourself/company the order. This requires a subject line. Make sure to set SMTP properties of the PayPal object 
/// and the FromEmail and ToEmail properties as well.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="subject"></param>
private void EmailUs(string subject)
{
    MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
    mailObj.From = new MailAddress(this.FromEmail);
    mailObj.Subject = subject;
    mailObj.To.Add(new MailAddress(this.ToEmail));
    mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailObj.Body = "<br />"
    + "Transaction ID: " + this.TXN_ID + "<br />"
    + "Transaction Type:" + this.TXN_Type + "<br />"
    + "Payment Type: " + this.PaymentType + "<br />"
    + "Payment Status: " + this.PaymentStatus + "<br />"
    + "Pending Reason: " + this.PendingReason + "<br />"
    + "Payment Date: " + this.PaymentDate + "<br />"
    + "Receiver Email: " + this.ReceiverEmail + "<br />"
    + "Invoice: " + this.Invoice + "<br />"
    + "Item Number: " + this.ItemNumber + "<br />"
    + "Item Name: " + this.ItemName + "<br />"
    + "Quantity: " + this.Quantity + "<br />"
    + "Custom: " + this.Custom + "<br />"
    + "Payment Gross: " + this.PaymentGross + "<br />"
    + "Payment Fee: " + this.PaymentFee + "<br />"
    + "Payer Email: " + this.PayerEmail + "<br />"
    + "First Name: " + this.PayerFirstName + "<br />"
    + "Last Name: " + this.PayerLastName + "<br />"
    + "Street Address: " + this.PayerAddress + "<br />"
    + "City: " + this.PayerCity + "<br />"
    + "State: " + this.PayerState + "<br />"
    + "Zip Code: " + this.PayerZipCode + "<br />"
    + "Country: " + this.PayerCountry + "<br />"
    + "Address Status: " + this.PayerAddressStatus + "<br />"
    + "Payer Status: " + this.PayerStatus + "<br />"
    + "Verify Sign: " + this.VerifySign + "<br />"
    + "Notify Version: " + this.NotifyVersion + "<br />";

    SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient();

    objSmtp.Host = this.SmtpHost;
    objSmtp.Port = System.Int32.Parse(this.SmtpPort);
    objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    objSmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.FromEmail, this.FromEmailPassword);
    objSmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    objSmtp.Send(mailObj);
}

#endregion

#region "Mail the Customer the Order details"

private void EmailBuyer(string subject, string message)
{
    MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
    mailObj.From = new MailAddress(this.FromEmail);
    mailObj.Subject = subject;
    mailObj.Body = message;
    mailObj.To.Add(new MailAddress(this.PayerEmail));
    mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient();

    objSmtp.Host = this.SmtpHost;
    objSmtp.Port = System.Int32.Parse(this.SmtpPort);
    objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    objSmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.FromEmail, this.FromEmailPassword);
    objSmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    objSmtp.Send(mailObj);
}

#endregion

#region "Fill Properties"

private void fillProperties()
{
    this.RequestLength = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.ToString();
    this.PayerCity = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["address_city"];
    this.PayerCountry = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["address_country"];
    this.PayerCountryCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["address_country_code"];
    this.PayerState = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["address_state"];
    this.PayerAddressStatus = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["address_status"];
    this.PayerAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["address_street"];
    this.PayerZipCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["address_zip"];
    this.PayerFirstName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["first_name"];
    this.PayerLastName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["last_name"];
    this.PayerBusinessName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payer_business_name"];
    this.PayerEmail = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payer_email"];
    this.PayerID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payer_id"];
    this.PayerStatus = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payer_status"];
   // this.PayerPhone = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["contact_phone"];
    this.Business = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["business"];
    this.ItemName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["item_name"];
    this.ItemNumber = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["item_number"];
    this.Quantity = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["quantity"];
    this.ReceiverEmail = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["receiver_email"];
    this.ReceiverID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["receiver_id"];
    this.Custom = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["custom"];
   // this.Memo = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["memo"];
    this.Invoice = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["invoice"];
    this.Tax = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["tax"];
    this.QuantityCartItems = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["num_cart_items"];
    this.PaymentDate = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payment_date"];
    this.PaymentStatus = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payment_status"];
    this.PaymentType = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["payment_type"];
    this.PendingReason = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["pending_reason"];
    this.TXN_ID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["txn_id"];
    this.TXN_Type = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["txn_type"];
    this.PaymentFee = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["mc_fee"];
    this.PaymentGross = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["mc_gross"];
    this.NotifyVersion = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["notify_version"];
   // this.VerifySign = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["verify_sign"];
}

#endregion




}
```

Any thoughts of the possible issues here?

Comment: Have somehow got around the issue of ASP.NET only having one form, which is probably already present? Are you using the PayPal button widget?

Comment: Yes I am using the PayPal button; how I got it to work is through adding and empty <form></form> tag above each button and it worked without issues.

Comment: Only issue with that is nobody knows why it works that way. Hopefully the request code will help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button HTML from the PayPal site is embedded in a form tag. You can only have one form on an ASP.NET page and ASP.NET provides its own. If you have a master page, then the form tag is in there and it is applied to every page in the site when they are merged with the master at runtime.

I found an [elegant solution](http://jerschneid.blogspot.com/2007/03/hide-form-tag-but-leave-content.html) on Jeremy Schneider's blog that consists of a custom HtmlForm class that can have the form tag rendering toggled on and off. The class is called GhostForm and has a property, RenderFormTag. When RenderFormTag is set to false, it doesn't render the opening or closing tags, but does render all of the contents. Reference the custom GhostForm class and in the code-behind of the form on which you are placing the button, place the following in the Page_Load to disable the master page form tag:

Usage:

```
public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         GhostForm mainForm = new GhostForm();
         mainForm.RenderFormTag = false;
         .....     
     }
         // Send your data to PayPal :-)
     .....
 }
```

**IMPORTANT:** make sure you are signed into the sandbox BEFORE sending this request.

**UPDATE:** Check out these instructional videos: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-1-architectural-discussion-and-overview

Like you, I used the IPN code from John Mendez. Here's where I send and receive from PayPal:

```
string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive);

//Set values for the request back to PayPal
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

//Send the request to PayPal 
StreamWriter streamOut = 
    new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
streamOut.Write(strRequest);
streamOut.Close();

// Get the response from PayPal
StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();
```

Hopefully this helps. 500 errors could be anything...

Comment: Very Helpful Indeed; For some reason I am still seeing the error; But I did benefit alot thnx. Would it be possible since you had John's code running maybe create a guide on how to deploy it? it would be very useful...thank you sorry for the trouble...

Comment: I just incorporated John's code into a class in my projects - it's then part of my Web App DLL. I put out some blog posts on PayPal here: http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/paypal THIs blog helped me also: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/paypalintegration/paypalintegration.asp

Comment: I added a video link to the answer.

Comment: I marked your answer as the solution; I found what I was looking for in the video you sent .... thank you

Comment: Thanks :-) Which part were you having probs with, just out of curiosity?