# passing simple data between asp.net applications using post

Tags: asp.net, post, between

I want only to pass a string between 2 applications (webform and mvc3) using the most easy way. Not web-service, single sign-on, membership api. Just a string that can't be seen in the  browser bar. I would like an example sending from a textbox and a button and getting to show on the label. Any reference? Thanks!

Comment: You can pass it as part of the URL (get method)

Comment: it's a sensitive data, can't be seen in the browser bar.

Answer (score 0):

page1.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" PostBackUrl="page2.aspx" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

and in page2.aspx code boehind:

```
Label1.Text = Request.Form["TextBox1"];
```

Comment: it did not work... the page2 is a MVC3 page and receive a null value

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of time...i found the only solution that worked for me...StringBuilder

[Response.Redirect which POSTs data to another URL in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062078/response-redirect-which-posts-data-to-another-url-in-asp-net)

i think that is not the best way to do this, but worked for me.

thanks for all!!