# Buying many products at once from a webshop

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7, webshop

It's quite simple to program just one product to get sold via my payment system (api.payson.se) but buying many products at the same time in various amounts posed trouble for me since it was not implemented and I didn't have a good idea how to do it. Now I have a solution that I just put together which works but the modelling and control flow is kind of very quick and dirty and I wonder whether this is even acceptable or should need a rewrite. The system now behaves so that I can enter the shop (step 1) and enter the amounts for the products I want to buy

[image]

Then if I press Buy ("Köp") my Python calculates the sum correctly and this works whatever combination of amounts and products I have saying which the total is and this page could also list the specification but that is not implemented yet:
[image]
The total sum is Swedish currency is correct and it has written an order to my datastore with status "unpaid" and containing which products are ordered and what amount for every product in the datastore:
[image]
The user can then either cancel the purchase or go on and actually pay through the payment system api.payson.se:
[image]
So all I need to do is listen to the response from Payson and update the status of the orders that get paid. But my solution does not look very clean and I wonder if I can go on with code like that, the data model is two stringlists, one with the amounts and one with which product (Item ID) since that was the easiest way I could solve it but it is then not directly accessible and only from the lists. Is there a better data model I can use?

The code that does the handling is slightly messy and could use a better data model and a better algorithm than just strings and lists:

```
class ShopHandler(NewBaseHandler):

    @user_required
    def get(self):
        user = \
            auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id'
                ]))
        self.render_jinja('shop.htm', items=Item.recent(), user=user)
        return ''

    @user_required
    def post(self, command):
        user = \
            auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id'
                ]))
        logging.info('in shophandler http post item id'+self.request.get('item'))

        items = [ self.request.get('items[1]'),self.request.get('items[2]'),self.request.get('items[3]'),self.request.get('items[4]'),self.request.get('items[5]'),self.request.get('items[6]'),self.request.get('items[7]'),self.request.get('items[8]')   ]   

        amounts = [ self.request.get('amounts[1]'),self.request.get('amounts[2]'),self.request.get('amounts[3]'),self.request.get('amounts[4]'),self.request.get('amounts[5]'),self.request.get('amounts[6]'),self.request.get('amounts[7]'),self.request.get('amounts[8]')  ]
        total = 0
        total = int(self.request.get('amounts[1]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[1]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[1]') else total
        total = total + int(self.request.get('amounts[2]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[2]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[2]') else total
        total = total + int(self.request.get('amounts[3]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[3]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[3]') else total
        total = total + int(self.request.get('amounts[4]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[4]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[4]') else total
        total = total + int(self.request.get('amounts[5]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[5]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[5]') else total
        total = total + int(self.request.get('amounts[6]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[6]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[6]') else total
        total = total + int(self.request.get('amounts[7]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[7]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[7]') else total
        total = total + int(self.request.get('amounts[8]'))* long(Item.get_by_id(long(self.request.get('items[8]'))).price_fraction()) if self.request.get('amounts[8]') else total
        logging.info('total:'+str(total))
        trimmed = str(total)+',00'
        order = model.Order(status='UNPAID')
        order.items = items
        order.amounts = amounts
        order.put()
        logging.info('order was written')
        ExtraCost = 0
        GuaranteeOffered = 2
        OkUrl = 'http://' + self.request.host + r'/paysonreceive/'
        Key = '3110fb33-6122-4032-b25a-329b430de6b6'
        text = 'niklasro@gmail.com' + ':' + str(trimmed) + ':' + str(ExtraCost) \
            + ':' + OkUrl + ':' + str(GuaranteeOffered) + Key
        m = hashlib.md5()

        BuyerEmail = user.email
        AgentID = 11366
        self.render_jinja('order.htm', order=order, user=user, total=total, Generated_MD5_Hash_Value = hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest(), BuyerEmail=user.email, Description='Bnano Webshop', trimmed=trimmed, OkUrl=OkUrl, BuyerFirstName=user.firstname, BuyerLastName=user.lastname)
```

My model for the order, where not all fields are used, is

```
class Order(db.Model):
  '''a transaction'''
  item = db.ReferenceProperty(Item)
  items = db.StringListProperty()
  amounts = db.StringListProperty()
  owner = db.UserProperty()
  purchaser = db.UserProperty()
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  status = db.StringProperty( choices=( 'NEW', 'CREATED', 'ERROR', 'CANCELLED', 'RETURNED', 'COMPLETED', 'UNPAID', 'PAID' ) )
  status_detail = db.StringProperty()
  reference = db.StringProperty()
  secret = db.StringProperty() # to verify return_url
  debug_request = db.TextProperty()
  debug_response = db.TextProperty()
  paykey = db.StringProperty()
  shipping = db.TextProperty()
```

And the model for a product ie an item is

```
class Item(db.Model):
  '''an item for sale'''
  owner = db.UserProperty() #optional
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  price = db.IntegerProperty() # cents / fractions, use price_decimal to get price in dollar / wholes
  image = db.BlobProperty()
  enabled = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  silver = db.IntegerProperty() #number of silver

  def price_dollars( self ):
    return self.price / 100.0

  def price_fraction( self ):
    return self.price / 100.0

  def price_silver( self ): #number of silvers an item "is worth"
    return self.silver / 1000.000

  def price_decimal( self ):
    return decimal.Decimal( str( self.price / 100.0 ) )

  def price_display( self ):
    return str(self.price_fraction()).replace('.',',')

  @staticmethod
  def recent():
    return Item.all().filter( "enabled =", True ).order('-created').fetch(10)
```

I think you now have an idea what's going on and that this kind of works towards the user but the code is not looking good. Do you think I can leave the code like this and go on and keep this "solution" or must I do a rewrite to make it more proper? There are only 8 products in the store and with this solution it becomes difficult to add a new Item for sale since then I must reprogram the script which is not perfect.

Could you comment or answer, I'd be very glad to get some feedback about this quick and dirty solution to my use case.

Thank you

### Update

I did a rewrite to allow for adding new products and the following seems better than the previous:

```
class ShopHandler(NewBaseHandler):

    @user_required
    def get(self):
        user = \
            auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id'
                ]))
        self.render_jinja('shop.htm', items=Item.recent(), user=user)
        return ''

    @user_required
    def post(self, command):
        user = \
            auth_models.User.get_by_id(long(self.auth.get_user_by_session()['user_id'
                ]))
        logging.info('in shophandler http post')

        total = 0
        order = model.Order(status='UNPAID')

        for item in self.request.POST:
            amount = self.request.POST[item]
            logging.info('item:'+str(item))
            purchase = Item.get_by_id(long(item))
            order.items.append(purchase.key())
            order.amounts.append(int(amount))
            order.put()
            price = purchase.price_fraction()
            logging.info('amount:'+str(amount))
            logging.info('product price:'+str(price))
            total = total + price*int(amount)

        logging.info('total:'+str(total))
        order.total = str(total)
        order.put()
        trimmed = str(total).replace('.',',') + '0'
        ExtraCost = 0
        GuaranteeOffered = 2
        OkUrl = 'http://' + self.request.host + r'/paysonreceive/'
        Key = '6230fb54-7842-3456-b43a-349b340de3b8'
        text = 'niklasro@gmail.com' + ':' + str(trimmed) + ':' \
            + str(ExtraCost) + ':' + OkUrl + ':' \
            + str(GuaranteeOffered) + Key
        m = hashlib.md5()
        BuyerEmail = user.email  # if user.email else user.auth_id[0]
        AgentID = 11366
        self.render_jinja(
            'order.htm',
            order=order,
            user=user,
            total=total,
            Generated_MD5_Hash_Value=hashlib.md5(text).hexdigest(),
            BuyerEmail=user.email,
            Description='Bnano Webshop',
            trimmed=trimmed,
            OkUrl=OkUrl,
            BuyerFirstName=user.firstname,
            BuyerLastName=user.lastname,
            )
```

Comment: It is much better then you have been before. Right now you can don't worry about addition of new items ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, this is a really strange code. If you will want to add new items in you shop you must rewrite you shop's script.
At the first unlink your items from interface, you must send POST request to controller with your items ids and quantity, i don know how work gae request object, but it must be like that:
from your order page make POST request with dict of items which really need {"item_id":"qnt"}.
When in the controller you can fetch all objects like:

```
for item, qnt in request.POST:
    {do something with each item, for example where you can sum total}
```

and etc
Don't link controllers with your interfaces directly. You must write more abstraction code, if you want make really flexible app.

Comment: But how do I actually POST the data as a dict? How should the fields look? I don't know how to POST something like `{"item_id":"qnt"}`. Please inform more if you can.

Comment: I'm going to recode it with this as the amount field `<input class="standard_input" name="{{ item.key().id()}}" size="2" autocomplete="off" type="text">` then I'll get a dict with name item_id and value amount. Do you think that will work better and in a way you propose? Otherwise I don't know how to POST a dict from a template.

Comment: I rewrote it to a better shape and posted the new version to the original question. The new version seems much better and allows for adding new items but I'm not sure if I thought of everything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to focus on one very obvious problem with your code, but there are lots of problems with it that I'm not going to get into.  My advice is to stop right now.  You're implementing a web-based payment system.  You really should leave that to people with more skills and experience.  "Web-based" is a pretty difficult thing to get right whilst ensuring security, but an online payment system is the sort of thing that well-paid consultants with decades of experience are well-paid for, and they still manage to get it wrong pretty often.  You're opening yourself up to a lot of legal liability.

If you're still dead set on it, please read [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) cover to cover, possibly several times.  Python is a very different language to whatever classical OOP language you're mentally cramming into it.  After that, at least leaf through the other documentation.  If you're having trouble with these, pick up an O'Reilly book on Python; approaching it from another angle should help.  After you done all this (and maybe at the same time), write as much code as you can that is not going to get you sued into oblivion if you do it wrong.  Then *maybe* you can write an order/payment system.

I'm sorry if this sounds harsh, but the world doesn't need any more shoddy web stores; 1999 took care of that for us.

Anyway, on to your code :D When you write something repetitive and copy-pasted like this:

```
items = [ self.request.get('items[1]'),self.request.get('items[2]'),self.request.get('items[3]'),self.request.get('items[4]'),self.request.get('items[5]'),self.request.get('items[6]'),self.request.get('items[7]'),self.request.get('items[8]')   ]
```

You should be thinking to yourself, "Wait a second!  Repetitive task are exactly what computers are designed to do."  You could get your text editor to do it (see Vim Macros), but concise (but not too concise ;) code is always better than long code, since you make it faster to maintain, less prone to programmer error, and easier to debug, not to mention the amount of time you save not copying and pasting, so let's improve the code.

Here's how I would revise this in Python (advanced programmers do this in their heads, or just skip to the end):

```
#1. with a for loop
MAX_ITEMS = 8
items = []
for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
    items.append(self.request.get('items[{}]'.format(i + 1))

#2. with a list comprehension
MAX_ITEMS = 8
items = [self.request.get('items[{}]'.format(i + 1)) for i in range(MAX_ITEMS)]
```

Actually, having a limit to the number of items is rather amateurish and will only frustrate your users.  You can fix it like this:

```
items = []
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        items.append(self.request[i + 1]) #attempt to get the next item
    except IndexError as exc: #but if it fails...
        break #we must be at the last one
    i += 1
```

I think this is the way you should leave it for now because it's clear but not repetitive.  However, you could shorten it even further using functions from [the `itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

A few quick tips:

- Avoid string concatenation, especially where user-supplied strings and especially especially when user-supplied string from over the web are concerned.  Use str.format and `"%d" % (5,)` modulus string formatting.  BONUS: You don't have to convert everything to strings!
- Get those constants (e.g., `ExtraCost = 2`) out of the middle and put them somewhere safe (at the top of the module, or in a special file in the package)
- You trust the user *way* too much: At `for item in self.request.POST:`, you're assuming everything in the request is going to be an item, and you do **zero** validation.
- Please, please, please.  **Never** turn off autocomplete.  I really don't know why that attribute exists, except to annoy.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. My code could complete purchases right away which I'm sure you're so skilled that you can do in your API head. Do you have Python implants so you can hash MD5 in your head? I really thought not looping was ugly and therefore I posted the code here for a strategy how to loop. The rest are details like string handling in python that I can fix in refactoring. To save both which item and which amount of that item for many items, as said it's like a dict and I followed your advice and abandoned the `item[]` in favor of pairs of `item.key().id()` and amount.

Comment: The only input field except submit is now `<input class="standard_input" name="{{ item.key().id()}}" size="2" type="text">` that will post the number of that particular item as value for that item. So isn't it the truth I'm "assuming" that everything in the request is going to be an item? I agree my first version was rather terrible but it could complete purchases which you can't do in your head and my objective was to enable purchases rather than writing clean code. I can write clean code but it means less than being able to actually complete purchases. I'm glad for the constructive criticism

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: I need to clarify.  I'm not saying I can _execute_ code in my head like some sort of Rain Man.  I'm saying I can revise verbose code to concise code mentally.

You misunderstand what refactoring means.  It doesn't mean fixing bugs or poor coding practices after you've put the code into production.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: Regarding the input, your HTML specifies one input, but unless you're running in a very controlled, secure environment, the data coming from the client cannot be guaranteed to be generated from your HTML.  There are any number of browser plugins and other software (malicious and legit) that let you modify POST data, so you can't trust it to be of a certain format.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: Regarding your strategy of "post buggy code now, fix later", you should really tread more carefully, or else you end up with really simple bugs [like First State Superannuation in Australia mistakenly permitting users access to other's reports](http://www.theage.com.au/it-pro/security-it/super-bad-first-state-set-police-on-man-who-showed-them-how--770000-accounts-could-be-ripped-off-20111018-1lvx1.html).