# How redirected user with method POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, redirect

How to redirect a user from the action with POST request?

I have:

```
public ViewResult AddMoneyOnPay()
        {
            Onpay onpay = new Onpay();
            onpay.convert = "yes";
            onpay.pay_mode = "fix";
            onpay.price_final = "true";

            return View(onpay);
        }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMoneyOnPay", "Transaction", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Onpay</legend>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pay_mode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pay_mode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.currency)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.currency)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pay_for)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pay_for)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.md5)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.md5)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.convert)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.convert)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.url_success)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.url_success)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.url_fail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.url_fail)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.note)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.note)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.one_way)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.one_way)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.price_final)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.price_final)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.direct_no)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.direct_no)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

action POST

```
[HttpPost]
        public ViewResult AddMoneyOnPay(Onpay onpay)
        {
            string secretKEy = "fH12312IO";
            onpay.md5 = GetHash(string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", onpay.pay_mode, onpay.price, onpay.currency, onpay.pay_for, onpay.convert, secretKEy));
            //SEND POST to url http://paysite.ru/blablabla
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `AddMoneyOnPay` method return an `ActionResult` and then write:

```
return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

Comment: The post data will be populated into your `Onpay` object - do all of your processing of it in your POST overload of `AddMoneyOnPay()`, then redirect the user using `Redirect()`.

Comment: @simply denis - in other words - do it in two steps. Process your data from a POST in `AddMoneyOnPay(Onpay onpay)` and then, once processed and saved (or whatever), redirect the user. Redirecting is always a `GET`. There is one other theoretical option - a 307 "temporary redirect" but in practice it isn't really a solution I don't think. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get

Comment: @simplydenis, in your action replace the `return View(onpay);` line with `return Redirect(returnUrl);` where `returnUrl` will be pointing to the url you are willing to redirect.