# load a page using POST to iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I want to create an iframe with other page visible inside. The page is outside my domain. Normally I do it like that:

```
$('<iframe />').attr('src','www.thepage.com?data=1').appendTo('body')
```

But if `www.thepage.com` is accessible via POST instead of GET, how should I load it? `$.ajax( type:'POST',...)` fails due to `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Answer (score 1):

Load in a temporary page that contains a form with the fields you need (hidden) and use Javascript to submit the form.

This happens to be a previous question that I asked.  [Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get)

Look at the answer from Pavlo.  You can see how he's creating an html page with a form that does a submit on load of the body.