# Loading a POST page into <iframe> without having to use javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637382/1184247) that addresses "POSTing to an iframe using JavaScript".

> ### My scenario:
>
> I am not allowed to use JavaScript or any of its libraries. Only thing I can use is PHP and HTML.
>
> - **Page1.php:**
>
>   ```
>      <form action="Page2.php">
>           <input type="....  >
>            .
>            .
>            .
>      </form>
>   ```
> - **Page2.php:**
>
>   ```
>      <iframe src="http://externalsite.com/post-to-this-address-thru-iframe">
>      </iframe>
>   ```

This is always possible when JavaScript is used. Using PHP's post functions like curl also won't do. Is there really a source of light for me?

Comment: using <form target="name_of_iframe"> might help

Comment: @SoaicaMircea but how can he refer to name_of_iframe which is there in another page?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Post directly to http://externalsite.com/post-to-this-address-thru-iframe

Comment: as @SoaicaMircea has stated, if you apply a name to the iframe and then set your form's target to that name, it should post to that iframe with the action you have specified...

Comment: I would agree with @andreas, I cannot see a way that you would be able to accomplish this without the use of any JavaScript/JQuery

Answer (score -1):

As per my comment.

1. Add a name attribute to your iframe.
2. Set the target of your form to the name of the iframe.

http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/GZPqM/

**Note** - Seems JSFiddle doesn't like you posting whilst on their site, as a result you will get some weird JSON output.

Comment: As had to be pointed out to myself (I have subsequently deleted my answer), the `<iframe>` is **not** on the same page!

Answer (score -1):

If you have control over **Page2.php** and **http://externalsite.com/** you can concatenate all data posted from the form as GET request inside iframe src field:

```
<iframe src="http://externalsite.com/post-to-this-address-thru-iframe/?param1=val1&param2=val2">
</iframe>
```