# OAuth: Receive callback with parameters as POST data

Tags: python, oauth

I'm new to OAuth, I'm using the [`oauth2` library on Python](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) to get my work done.

Currently when I receive a callback from the server, the parameters come in the URL as:

```
http://mydomain/?oauth_verifier=(SOME_DATA)&oauth_token=(SOME_DATA)&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to instruct the server to somehow `POST` those parameters (`oauth_verifier`, `oauth_token`, `oauth_callback_confirmed`) to me as a callback and not show them in the URL (as a GET request)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not possible to encode the callback parameters as a POST request. The [OAuth 1.0 Spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/) says that the provider issues an HTTP Redirect to the callback URL:

> If the Consumer provided a callback URL in oauth_callback (as
>   described in Consumer Directs the User to the Service Provider), the
>   Service Provider constructs an HTTP GET request URL, and redirects the
>   User’s web browser to that URL with the following parameters:

Since an HTTP Redirect [can only be a GET, not a POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get), your callback can only contain the parameters in the URL.