# Redirecting a GET request to another app's POST request in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, redirect

I have a controller action that is triggered by a GET route, which under some conditions, I want to redirect to the POST route of another app on another server.

I'm aware of `redirect_to "http://somewhere.com/thing_to_post_to"` but there doesn't seem to be a way of specifying the http method. This intended for AJAX requests not pages, so it isn't acceptable to return a javascript to direct the browser.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect_to uses HTTP status code to make the redirection, so it would likely be a GET, here's antoher explanation to use 307 status code

[Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get)

but is not very well implemented among all browsers, so i suggest using a session variable to pass parameters among the views or something similar.

Comment: thanks, probably easiest for me to edit the routing at the other end to just use get even though it's a create action, not the same aesthetic, but it works.