# Java : redirect from backing bean with POST parameters

Tags: java

I have the following code to submit a form with a get mechanism :

```
ExternalContext extCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) extCtx.getSession(false);

String formAction = obj.getRedirectURL();
session.setAttribute("formAction", formAction);
session.setAttribute("param1", param1);
session.setAttribute("param2", param2);
extCtx.redirect(formAction);
```

How can i submit the same request with POST mechanism.

Comment: [You can't redirect using POST](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14055241/4310386)

Comment: Then, Is there another way to submit a POST to an external site ?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/4310386)

Comment: or you can just google it

Comment: Thanks  Janith , I already googled it before posting my question. And i didn't find a solution so far.