# Preserving POST data and redirect to another domain

Tags: asp.net, http, post

I have two domains innosia.com and sorainnosia.com, the innosia.com is an old domain that I wish whoever visit it got redirect to sorainnosia.com including the POST data that they are posting to. Because currently there is an old windows application that POST data to the old domain that I cannot modify at client side, and wish the data to be POST to new domain instead only by doing changing to innosia.com without modifying client side windows application.

I find out that HTTP status 301 that redirect to another domain will not preserve the POST data. I search on google and stackoverflow but can't find any answer. My web is built using ASP.NET MVC 3.0, anyone has any solution?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some HTTP clients just can't properly handle 301 redirection of their POST requests.

You could however change the old DNS record to point to the new server, or deploy a simple proxy (like Apache) on the old URL to forward the request behind the scenes to the new server.