# How can I change the http request from Post to Get in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

Suppose I have a view which will take a POST request. After the validation check pass, I need to redirect the request to another HTML/view with a request with GET method:

```
def view1(request):
    if request.POST:
       form = TempForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           return redirect(request, 'view2')

def view2(request):
    if request.POST:
       #POST stuff here
    else:
       #GET stuff here
```

My problem is that after the `form.is_valid()`, the redirect request will be passed as a POST method. My ultimate goal is to redirect the view2 with GET method.

Can I do such thing in Django?

Comment: The redirect won't be a POST: http://stackoverflow.com/a/47735/396300

Comment: But I got this sequences:  
[11/Feb/2013 03:05:51] "GET /core/login_retrieval/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2123
[11/Feb/2013 03:05:53] "POST /core/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2429

Did I use a wrong redirect function?

Comment: I think you need to create a url with variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) class to redirect to any URL you like. Since it's a redirect, the request will be a GET request (POST isn't possible with http redirect - that's a restriction of the http protocol).

If you need to add GET parameters you could simply create the GET string yourself -

```
get_string = "?"
get_strint += "my_param=" + my_variable + "&"
get_string += "my_other_param=" + my_other_variable
return HttpResponseRedirect('/my_url/' + get_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The user agent (the browser) decides if it gets redirected with POST or GET. Most browsers will switch from POST to GET if they get redirected. The only way I know you can get redirected and stay in POST is if you do it explicitly, such as with curl -X POST.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get