# How to properly route POST request to new URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

We are launching new site on new platform. Since we aren't able to rewrite all existing services on new platform, I need to route all the service requests to new URL where existing site will be moved.

For example. Our current URL is `http://www.site.com`. With launch of the new site this URL will serve new site, and old site will be moved to `http://old.site.com`. Lets say our existing service that handles post request is now located at `http://www.site.com/service_one` but will then be moved to `http://old.site.com/service_one`.

How do I properly route all post request that will come to `http://www.site.com/service_one` -> `http://old.site.com/service_one`?

UPDATE:
The real question here is can the POST request even be routed to new URL with .htaccess?

Comment: I just need to route post requests from www.site.com/service_one to old.site.com/service_one, that means including post parameters

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about HTTP redirection, [you can't reliably do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get), unfortunately. According to the HTTP 1.1 spec, the code to make the client redo the POST request to the new URL is 307, but some browsers do not respect that.

if you're able to use server side rewriting (using mod_rewrite, for example) rather than client side redirection, it will work. That assumes your new site is hosted along the old one in the same servers, however.

Comment: yes I am hosting the sites on the same servers and I can use mode_rewrite, but I don't know how to add proper rules into .htaccess...