# Call JSP of another server from My Server

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have two server and i can call jsp of another server from my server's jsp.

like following code.
First Server JSP.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/Second_App/index.jsp">
            Name : <input type="text" name="name"/>
            Surname : <input type="text" name="surname"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click on Submit the control will go in second server it will take name as parameter and put it into my Second Server's jsp.

Second Server JSP.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <% 
            String name = (String) request.getParameter("name");
            String surName = (String) request.getParameter("surname");
        %>
        Name    : <%= name %>
        Surname : <%= surName %>
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to do exact same thing using Servlet.

I tried with Servlet's Redirect my control will go to Second server but because of Redirect it will not take "name" peramater.

I tried with Forward but it is also not working because it is finding that jsp in first server.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("http://server2/app1/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

My concern is JSP is Servlet. If this is done with jsp that means there should be some way for doing it with servlet.

Thanks.

Comment: Append the request parameters while redirecting !

Comment: like this request.setAttribute("jsonString", "This Is Json String"); response.sendRedirect("localhost:8080/WebApplication4/index.jsp"); ?

Comment: No as part of URL query string .

Comment: Sorry i have lots of Parameter to Pass so Query String is not an Option. Even its not Secure.

Answer (score 1):

Send you form parameter from Servlet in this way. Next JSP will get `name parameter` from request.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("http://server2/app1/index.jsp?name=setUserNameHereFromRequest");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

With sendRedirect

```
response.sendRedirect("http://server2/app1/index.jsp?name=setUserNameHereFromRequest");
```

Comment: sir I have read that request dispatcher cannot go outside the web application. We need to use sendRedirect for the same. Are you sure your solution works?

Comment: Yes I am sure. You can add parameter like I did. Answer edited.

Comment: Prasad is Right it will go for finding jsp in its context. i already mention that in Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use response.sendRedirect("url_where_to_redirect");

Here the current request will get end and it will redirect to another context.

But here you can call one external server url that's all. I think you need to show page from second server according to your request with url from your current page. If you need that then you should use some code to handle the request in the second server application.

Comment: In Second JSP i am using following code to get Request Peramater. <% 
            String jsonString1 = (String) request.getAttribute("jasonString");
            String jsonString2 = (String) request.getParameter("jasonString");
        %>
        Json String
        <%= jsonString1 %>
        <%= jsonString2 %>

Comment: How is your redirect url?

Comment: Please check my First JSP. i need exact that code in Servlet. Means That First jsp is doing work that i want to do it in Servlet.

Comment: Ok you can use query string to pass parameters. So you should have your url as response.sendRedirect("http://server2/app1/index.jsp?argument1=value&argument2=value2"); Later you can get values from your second server from request.getParameter("argument1");

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `sendRedirect()`

This method is used to redirect client request to some other location for further processing ,the new location is **available on different server or different context**. The web container handle this and transfer the request using  browser, and this request is visible in browser as a new request. Some time this is also called as client side redirect.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://server2/app1/index.jsp");
```

Comment: That means if i will use following code then i will get request peramater in JSP. request.setAttribute("jsonString", "This Is Json String");
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/WebApplication4/index.jsp");

Comment: No you can't set attribute in request and get the value while redirecting.Because it is entirely new request will trigger if you use redirect method.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect post requests using the HTTP 307, temporary redirect.

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT );  
response.addHeader("Location","target/example.jsp");
```

You can find more detailed information on this topic here:

[Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get/47735#47735)