# How to redirect to an external URL with POST parameters in a controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I redirect from a controller to an external URL using POST method and passing some parameters?

Basically I need to do automatically what a form would do.

I found Redirect method in my controller, but it only seems to accept a url string. No method nor parameters.

Comment: Do you need to redirect to the form after posting to it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do post with server side redirect. Options:

- perform POST on server and handle results servers side (does not work if you need cookies to be set or used on destination server by that post request)
- perform post to that server directly on browser side
- perform AJAX post to your server and normal post to destination server if you need to notify both.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Fluentx.Mvc from Nuget for this.

**Install Fluentx.Mvc from nuget**

You need to include in your code:

```
using Fluentx.Mvc;
```

**and the code to call a external URL with post:**

First create a Dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<string, object> 
          objData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

and insert values:

```
objData.Add("name", "John");

objData.Add("city", "NY");
```

After that, use return from Fluentx:

```
return this.RedirectAndPost("http://yourexternalurl", objData);
```

In your external url, you get values :

```
string strName = Request["nome"];
string strCity = Request["city"];
```

Comment: How do you send headers with this..?