# redirect 302 losing POST data

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have Global load balancer URL, whenever I hit the page with Global loadbalnacer URL its redirect to my local load balancer URL in a response to 302.

Below is the issue which i am facing on 302 redirect.

I have a form on my jsp page, when I am submitting my form via POST with required parameters to my Global load balancer URL, then browser sends a request to Global loadbalancer URL, it replies with a “302” and tells it to redirect to the local load balancer. We are getting to a server and drawing the page but losing the parameters due to the redirect request.

Is there way where i can  the avoid losing parameter in 302 redirect?

Comment: Instead of using a 302 redirect, use a 307 redirect

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a 302 redirect, use a 307 redirect.
For a more in deep explanation check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get)

Comment: Thanks, but that application is owned by different group .. and they are saying we have to handle the 302.. is there way to check the 302 status using javascript? and then i can do my stuff based on 302

Comment: I don't think you can check it with javascript, as it's handled by the browser, the other solution I see is to change the form method to from POST to GET; but I don't believe that is what you want

Comment: yeah, i dont want to change POST to GET.