# why is this php POST form not sending data

Tags: php

this is the page that authenticates youtube api and sets video upload location. the auth code does `GET` correctly

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
  $code=$_GET['code'];
  $scope=$_GET['scope'];
  print "<form action='youtube-api-samples/resumable_upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='code' value='$code' />
    <input type='hidden' name='scope' value='$scope' />
    video location: <input type='text' name='video'><br>
    <input type='submit'>
  </form>";
}
```

here is part of resumable_upload.php

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();

if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_POST['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}
```

I tested and its not receiving any variables from that form.

Comment: 302 is clearly from header('Location: ' . $redirect);

Comment: Is this related to [redirect 302 losing POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490380/redirect-302-losing-post-data)?

Comment: given it's calling header, clearly $_POST['code'] IS set

Comment: @YourCommonSense when it redirects to itself it looses the data

Comment: @qrsngky so it seems that i need to use cURL or modify apache to do 307 correct?

Comment: Try debug the code using `echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by having the program on a single page and removing the form action. I still don't know why the form isn't able to submit the data to another page.