# Process Django POST form, and then redirect to a new view passing an argument

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view that is processing a POST form in Django.  I wanted to do some validation on the information.  And then after, redirect to a view, using the data from the form.  I wouldn't like to keep this information in the URL.  What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

If you want to process some data from one view in another view, you can do something like below:

```
def process_view(request, username):
    ''' This is the view where you want to process the username '''
    # process the username ...
    return something

def login_view(request):
    ''' Main login form through which data is submitted '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username'] # the username submitted via form
        # do something ...
        # call the process_view below
        return process_view(request, username)
```

If, however, you want to ***login*** the user, you would need to set an authentication cookie on that user's browser. Setting cookies will also allow you to process the ***username*** in any view you want.

**Here's how you can set cookies:**

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']

        # set the cookie below
        request.session['username'] = username

        return something
```

**And now, if you want to access the *username* in any other view, do this:**

```
def some_view(request):
    username = request.session['username']
    # do something ...
    return something
```

I suggest you go with the second approach i.e. the *setting cookies* approach, since it is more effective than calling a view from another view.

Comment: Will the view that /thanks/ refers to have the data from the POST request from def form_view?  That is my intention.  So form_view processes a login and has a user name.  Then I want to use that username in a different view.

Comment: @corey I think I had misunderstood your question. Hang on while I update it.

Comment: @corey Hi, I've updated my answer. See if it helps ya.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not call the other view with the POST data, at the end of your view?

Or use a session (or cookies) to store the post data? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Otherwise see [Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get)

Comment: I've tried to call the other view with the POST data but am having difficulties.  Do you know the proper way to do this?