# Node.js with Express: how to redirect a POST request

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

I want to redirect from one URL request to another 'POST' request, like this:

```js
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/test');
});

app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('/test page');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listenning on port:3000');
});
```

However, I can't redirect to '/test' page because it is a POST request. 
So what should I do to make the redirection work, keeping the '/test' request POST?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the term 'page' are you looking at redirecting from 1 endpoint to another? Example `/` {GET} request to `/test` {POST}

Comment: sorry for the confusion. what I mean is redirecting from 'localhost:3000/' to 'localhost:3000/test'

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can do this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(307, '/test');
});
```

Which will preserve the send method.

For reference, the 307 http code spec is:

> 307 Temporary Redirect (since HTTP/1.1) In this occasion, the request
>   should be repeated with another URI, but future requests can still use
>   the original URI.2 In contrast to 303, the request method should not
>   be changed when reissuing the original request. For instance, a POST
>   request must be repeated using another POST request.

For more info, see: http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html

Comment: got it. So I just can't redirect to app.post('/test') if I use app.get('/'), right?

Comment: Not with a standard http redirect, you would need to set up some kind of proxy.

Comment: This solution forces another browser request. Server instructs browser, browser then makes another request. This is a roundabout method. Anyway i can redirect within Express directly to avoid having to go all the way to browser to make a request ?

Comment: @Koder - if you're doing it within Express/Node (without changing the URL) it's not really a redirect, so as mentioned you could use a proxy. If you have specific questions, it would probably be best to ask a new question and provide the specifics of your situation.

Comment: @Koder - if you indend the endpoint to be processed within your server - you can re-route internally - i.e re-enter the router.

Comment: Making root ('/') as post type stops get request on root. So, I find sending a autosubmit hidden form useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35353805/6712094

Comment: Thxn but do you have any idea how can I attach cookie with this? my context is that i'm redirecting in successful registration with `res.redirect(307, "/admin");` However I tried res.cookie with cookieParser but none seems to works since I have fetch request and it's not storing cookie or someting?

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind the middleware architecture: Each handler may manipulate the context, and either respond - or - call `next()`.

By this premise, the express router is basically a middleware function you may use after "correcting" the url.

(BTW, the request app is also a function, although I'm not sure if I recommend going back so early in the chain)

Here's a kind'a example:

```
const router = new require('express').Router()
const user = require('../model/user') 
//assume user implements:
//  user.byId(id) -> Promise<user>
//  user.byMail(email) -> Promise<user>

const reqUser = userPromise => (req, res, next) =>
   req.user
     ? next()
     : userPromise(req)
       .then(user => { req.user = user })
       .then(next, next)
//assume the sever that uses this router has a 
//standard (err, req, res, next) handler in the end of the chain...

const byId = reqUser( req => user.byId(req.params.id) )
const byMail = reqUser( req => user.byMail(req.params.mail) )

router.post('/by-id/:id/friends',
  byId,
  (req, res) => res.render('user-friends', req.user)
)

router.post('/by-email/:email/friends',
  byMail,
  (req, res, next) => {
     req.url = `/by-id/${req.user.id}/friends`
     next()
  }, 
  router
)
```

Comment: This one worked for me for firebase functions which is using express routing in single function.

Answer (score 5):

The only difference between 307 and 302 is that 307 guarantees that the method and the body will not be changed when the redirected request is made.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307

Answer (score 5):

I believe the question is that the node server is receiving a POST request but needs to redirect it to a different server as GET request. I recently had to deal with something similar. Here is how I solved it:

```
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use('incomin/url', proxy('forwarding:server', {
    //The proxyRqDecorator allows us to change a few things including the request type.

proxyReqOptDecorator: (proxyReqOpts, srcReq) => {
    proxyReqOpts.method = 'GET';
    return proxyReqOpts;
},

//The proxyReqPathResolver takes the Given URL and updates it to the forward path
proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout( () =>{
            var value = req.body.key;
            var resolvedPathValue = 'forwarding/url' + value;
            console.log(`Inside forward path. The resolved path is ${resolvedPathValue}`);
            resolve(resolvedPathValue);
        }, 200);
    });
}
}));
```

Keep in mind that the above proxyReqPathResolver is setup async. The synchronous vesrion and more info on express-http-proxy are described here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

These days I'ld also consider a redirect with the code `308`, e.g. with `express`

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => res.redirect(308, '/graphql'));
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308), `308` preserves not only the HTTP method, but also indicates this is a *permanent* redirect.