# How can I fix set headers in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to redirect from the condition of a mysql to a get method but it does not work. How could I solve it?

```
app.post('/responses/',(req,res)=>{
    var {text, context ={} } = req.body;
    var params = {
        input: {text},
        workspace_id: '07',
        context
    }`
    `assistant.message(params,(err,response) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(response);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        }
        if(response.context.rfc){
            var RFC = response.context.rfc;
            connection.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                connection.query(`SELECT * FROM test where RFC = '${RFC}'`, function (err, result, fields) {
                    if(result.length){
                        console.log("login");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('no login');
                        res.redirect('/home'); //Her not redirect.
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Because show this error: `hrow err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors ^Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: Please expand on *"it does not work"* with a [mcve].

Comment: per  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810114/node-js-with-express-how-to-redirect-a-post-request] , change redirect to `res.redirect(307, '/home');`

Comment: @Uma not work. The console show: `throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates you are trying to set headers after the response is already sent. From your sample code, looks like your API call (whatever `assistant.message` is) is returning RFC. You then attempt to redirect to another page, but you've *already* called `res.json`, which begins sending a response to the browser.

You need to refactor your controller a bit so that you only call `res.redirect` or `res.json`, not both.

Comment: Nelson how can I use another res?

Comment: You cannot set any headers or send the res again once it is sent.

Comment: You'll need to rearrange your if/else statements so you only fall through to `res.json` response if you _aren't_ redirecting or returning an error.