# Post Redirect with data

Tags: node.js, express

I'm tring ti redirect user request to another url on post with some additional data.

Lets say user do POST `/profile/update`
After I want to redirect user to another url with some additional data.
For example to: POST `/test body` with some body: `{"foo":"bar"}`

Is it possible to do ?
If yes then how :)

```
app.post('/profile/update', function(req, res) {
   res.redirect(307, '/test')
   // but dont know how to pass some body here: {"foo":"bar"}
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are doing it in the right way. Your data should be passed directly to the route `/test`. That is: if you do req.body in the code of the route `/test` after having redirected, you should see the data that came from `/profile/update`.
Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810114/node-js-with-express-how-to-redirect-a-post-request) and the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect).

If it confuses and you do not want to redirect I suggest you do something different. Create a controller  for the route `/test` (that is, move the code inside the route do a different script called testController.js and inside the route invoke it). Then just go with

```
app.post('/profile/update', function(req, res) {
   testController.test(req.body);
});
```