# Sending data from post request to get request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hey guys just started with nodejs and express so i came up with the situation where i want to send my data to my GET req from my POST req.Here is the code below for you to understand

```
app.post('/run-time',(req,res)=>{
    const stoptime=req.body.stop
    const plannedtime=req.body.planned
    const runtime=plannedtime-stoptime
    res.redirect('/run-time')
})
```

this is my POST req where i fetched the values from the form and then calculated the 'runtime' now then i have to redirect to specific GET route

```
app.get('/run-time',(req,res)=>{

})
```

so what i want is send the 'runtime' variable calulated in my POST req to my GET req here ..how can i do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect in expressjs while passing some context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38810114/9320884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been use that way But I think you can use querystring
querystring can contains data in url.

```
app.post('/run-time',(req,res)=>{
    const stoptime=req.body.stop
    const plannedtime=req.body.planned
    const runtime=plannedtime-stoptime 
    res.redirect(`/run-time?runtime={runtime}`);
})

app.get('/run-time',(req,res)=>{
    var runtime = req.query.runtime;
    //~ 
})
```

I think that way can be your solution.
But you have to change your code because It is not used like this.
Maybe many solution is.