# How to send data with redirect back in Express JS

Tags: node.js, express

Hello I am new to NodeJs. Currently I am working in node with Express framework.
I installed the express-back package in my project and now I want to send send back data to view from where post request fired.
Below is my code that I write:

**routes.js**

```
router.post('/register/user',Rules.UserRules.registerUser,UserController.registerUser)
```

**UserController.js**

```
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
registerUser = function (req, res, next) {

    // Validate request parameters, queries using express-validator
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    console.log("==== errors ===")
    console.log(errors.array())
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log("==== erorror founded ====")
        return res.redirect('/signup',{errors:errors})
    }else{
        console.log('--- form body ----')
        console.log(req.body)
    }

}
module.exports = {registerUser}
```

When I submit my form to this route then control moves to UserController and I validations fails then I want to send it back to view without defining the redirect path I just want to send it back to view from where request received with errors. But I did not find any useful solution yet.
Is there any idea that how I can achieve this target. Suggest any useful link for nodejs beginner.

Comment: you want send back ```req.body``` data to client??

Comment: @MohammadSadeghForoughi yes I send back errors to signup page

Answer (score 0):

use `res.send(errors)` it send errors to client at this route. but if you want to redirect it to another route and then send it to client you have to create `/signup` route and use `res.send(errors)` it send `errors` to client. by default ``` res```` will redirect to redirected route.

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res)=>{
//send error or do somethings.
res.json(req.body.errors);
})
```

Comment: When I wright following code "res.redirect('back')" then signup page loaded again but I can't send error messages with this. I can only send the status code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810114/node-js-with-express-how-to-redirect-a-post-request @RizwanSaleem