# How to Redirect within a POST request in node js

Tags: javascript, express, nodes

I am trying to redirect inside of the following method:

```
app.post('/api/generateAccount/', async (req, res) => 
{
// other stuff here
    res.redirect(`/404.html`); //just for testing
});
```

using the following fetch request:

```
 fetch('/api/generateAccount',
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                        });
```

using nodemon I have the following printed: GET /404.html 304 - - 0.487 ms

but unfortunately the web page never changes within the browser, what would be the fix for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810114/node-js-with-express-how-to-redirect-a-post-request

Comment: i have tried using     res.redirect(307, `/404`); but I get page not found