# Can I redirect from 'GET' to 'POST' query in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I want to load 'get-all' page when I am in a main page. The code is below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`express server is listening on port ${PORT}`) });

app.get('/', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.redirect('/get-all');
});

app.post('/create', (req: any, res: any) => {

});

app.post('/get-all', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.send('get all') // error: get all not found
});

app.post('/delete', (req: any, res: any) => {

});

app.post('/update', (req: any, res: any) => {

});
```

The error is: Cannot GET /get-all (I tried to run it via Postman).
I didn't find clear answer in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810114/node-js-with-express-how-to-redirect-a-post-request).

Comment: hm, you are right ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Redirects can switch a request **to** GET but not to POST.

---

It doesn't make much sense to do that anyway. GET requests are supposed to be Safe and Idempotent. Switching a POST request (which aren't) is a fairly dangerous form of unexpected behaviour. The request wouldn't have a body containing POST data anyway.

Your method is called "get-all" and doesn't seem to be storing/updating/changing anything anyway, so the proper verb to access it would be GET in the first place.