# redirect to certain route after a response using fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my problem, when I post from using the classic form post the
post goes to server if certain conditions are met the server then redirect to the specific page
but when I use fetch request for posting due to the need to model data a certain way a yet with similar request the server doesn't redirect me to the wanted page and it just stays where it is , any solution my bet is I need to add something to my fetch so the fetch will respond to the redirection sent by the server.

```js
// Front-End Code Fetch 
fetch('/pin', {
      credentials: "same-origin",
      mode: "same-origin",
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }, 
      body: JSON.stringify(inputJSON)
   })
// Back-End Code 
exports.pin = async (req, res, next) => {
        res.redirect(`/app`)
}

// Routing model
app.route('/pin')
    .post(authentication.pin) 
app.route('/app')
    .get(toAppControler.getApp)
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804)

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810253/3466729): you can't redirect a POST to a GET.
Can you add this to your code? This way you can either GET or POST /app?

```js
app.route('/app').post(...)
```