# res.redirect(/logout) is sending a get request, how to make it so that it sends a post request

Tags: node.js, express, routes, express-router

i have a function which under some conditions redirects using

```
return res.redirect('/logout');
```

i handle the above redirect using

```
app.route('/logout').post(users.signout);
```

but the problem is that res.redirect is using a get call and not a post call.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUjt4.png)

I do know i can just handle it as a get call but is there anyway to make it so that res.redirect raises a post call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js with Express: how to redirect a POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810114/node-js-with-express-how-to-redirect-a-post-request)

Comment: yes for the most part.
in the answer you mentioned
they used 
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('/test page');
});
in my case i don't have an app reference, i am just raising a res.redirect(/logout) do you happen to know how to do the same in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you can call POST method from redirect but there is something else you can do.

```
app.route('/logout/SpecificRoute').get(users.signout) {
    //Here you can write the code you wanted to execute in the POST method and if  
    //you want some data, you can use route params.
};
app.route('/logout').get(users.signout);
```

But make sure to call `app.route('/logout/SpecificRoute').get(users.signout)`before app.route('/logout/:DataParams').get(users.signout) if you are using routes with params as well.