# express.js - static files doesn't connect

Tags: javascript, css, express

Good people!
Why doesn't it redirect when I click the "Submit" button on the **login** page?

code in **index.js** file:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { "extensions": ["html", "css", "js"] }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/login.html'));
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    res.redirect('/chat');
});

app.get('/chat', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/chat.html'));
});
```

and **login.html**:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login.css">
    <title>Log in</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="/login" method="post" class="form">
            <h1>Enter to the chat</h1>
            <div class="username-container">
                <label for="username">Your name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/login.js"></script>
</body>
```

project structure:

```
  ./public
    ./css
      ./login.css
      ./styles.css
    ./js
      ./login.js
      ./main.js
    ./chat.html
    ./login.html
  ./index.js
```

To the browser console using the code from **login.js**:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
       event.preventDefault();

       console.log('Form submitted');

       socket.emit('login', {
           username: username.value.trim()
       });
});
```

"Form submitted" is displayed

But when I was still figuring out how to connect styles to the server in principle, when they were not connected, everything was fine with the redirect. By the way, there were MIME TYPE errors.

There are currently no errors in the console.

Comment: In your `index.js` file did you imported `const bodyParser = require('body-parser')` and inclued it `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` -  I mean it is required for a POST request to parse the data: [Node.js body parsing middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html): "Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property."

Comment: No, I'm using "app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));"

Comment: Still doesn't work with body-parser

Comment: You have `event.preventDefault();` in the event listener so the form isn't being submitted. Unless you have other code where you are manually submitting the form via Axios/fetch that isn't included in your post then the form isn't being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your index.js and let's see it'll help or not.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { "extensions": ["html", "css", "js"] }));
```

Comment: Still not redirecting to chat

Comment: Hey @Timur, can you just try this? res.redirect(307, '/chat'); 
"307 Temporary Redirect (since HTTP/1.1)" so let's see it will work or not.

Comment: No, it doesn’t work

Comment: Here, the same issue occurred.. just check this... 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810114/node-js-with-express-how-to-redirect-a-post-request

Comment: O! I just removed that from login.js - 
event.preventDefault();
and the redirection was successful!

Comment: wow! good.. :) @Timur

Answer (score 0):

Your code here blocks the submitting of the form with the `event.preventDefault()`.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
       event.preventDefault();

       console.log('Form submitted');

       socket.emit('login', {
           username: username.value.trim()
       });
});
```

Because you're blocking the default submit, no POST is ever sent to your server and thus you don't get a redirect.  It's unclear why you're blocking the default.  If you want it to submit, then just remove the `event.preventDefault()`:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
       console.log('Form submitted');
       socket.emit('login', { username: username.value.trim() });
});
```

Note, it may not be particularly useful to do the `socket.emit('login', ...)` because the moment this form submits, it will redirect and that will load a new page in the browser and thus throw away this socket.io connection and create a brand new one (if the new page that loads also establishes a socket.io connection).  So, you've sent a message on a socket that is just about the close.