# express.js, socket.io - data doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I have problem with **socket.io**.
When the user is redirected to /chat, then **chat-message** works there and messages with the name “undefined” are sent, but from “get-username” it is no longer possible to output data even to the console in the chat.html, although everything has been done, it seems , just like with a “chat message”.

**index.js**:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('get-username', data => {
        io.emit('set-username', {
            username: data.username
        }, () => {
            console.log(data.username); // this is displayed
        });
    });
    
    socket.on('chat-message', data => {
        io.emit('chat-message', {
            message: data.message,
            name: data.username
        });
    });
});
```

form in **login.html**:

```
        <form action="/login" method="post" class="form">
            <h1>Enter to the chat</h1>
            <div class="username-container">
                <label for="username">Your name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/login.js"></script>
```

code in **login.js**:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', () => { 
    const username = usernameInput.value.trim();

    socket.emit('get-username', {
        username: username
    });
});
```

in **chat.html**:

```
<form action="" class="form">
    <div class="username">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="10" readonly required>
    </div>
      ....
</form>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

and in **main.js**:

```
socket.on('set-username', data => {
    nameBlock.value = data.username;
    console.log(data.username);
});

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const message = input.value.trim();
    if (!message) return;

    socket.emit('chat-message', {
        message: message,
        name: nameBlock.value
    });

    input.value = '';
});

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerHTML = `<span>${data.name}</span>: ${data.message}`;
    chat.appendChild(item);

    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

there are no errors in the console

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking in your question.  It seems that the answer I supplied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77348481/816620) is related to this same code, but perhaps this is a different question?  Can you explain your question in more detail?  What are you expecting to happen?  What do you observe happening?  What have you tried to solve the problem?