# C# - jquery ajax posted params not passing to server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have this simple ajax request on the client side:

```
var name = $("#txtNewsletterName");
var email = $("#txtNewsletterEmail");

$.ajax({
    url: "/Handlers/Handler.ashx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        op: "register_to_newsletter",
        name: name.val(),
        email: email.val()
    },
    async: true
});
```

and this code on the C# server side:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    switch (context.Request["op"])
    {
        case "register_to_newsletter":
            string recipientName = context.Request["name"].Trim();
            string recipientEmail = context.Request["email"].Trim();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the data from the request is not passed to the server, so the `context.Request["op"]`, `context.Request["name"]` and `context.Request["email"]` are null.

I've also checked `context.Request.Form.AllKeys` and it's `string[0]`
So obviously the data does not get to the server.

When checking the Network tab in chrome debugger I see that there are 2 requests sent so I've added a screenshot of the Network data from chrome debugger:

1. [image: request #1]
2. [image: request #2]

Comment: What does your browser show in the request body?

Comment: Try enclosing your json object keys in quotations. Sometimes that makes the difference. 
So like this `"op": "register_to_newsletter",`

Comment: Is there a redirect before the POST?

Comment: You put images of Request headers, we need to see request body. Please post that

Comment: @ElwinArens, I've added 2 screenshots of the request for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get

Comment: I know but those images don't show Request body part they are just showing Request header part.

Comment: @LiranFriedman Can you get rid of the redirect?

Comment: @ElwinArens, which redirect ? I don't have a redirect...

Comment: @LiranFriedman Could you post another screenshot of the POST that actually shows the request data (this falls off the screen in the first one)

Comment: @LiranFriedman And remove the contentType from the AJAX call

Comment: @ElwinArens, I've posted another screenshot without the redirect and removed the content type from the ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a redirect occurring, which seems to be dropping the data.

If you look at the the second screenshot you see a GET HTTP 200, but the data is no longer in the request.

The redirect is from `"/Handlers/Handler.ashx"` to  `"/handlers/handler.ashx"`. Maybe there's an urlrewrite in the web.config that enforces lowercase urls and does a redirect if it matches an uppercase character?

What if you change the url to all lowercase:

```
url: "/handlers/handler.ashx",
```

And remove the contentType setting:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Because you're not deserializing the data on the server, but want to send it as the default contentType `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.
The *dataType* is for the response, the *contentType* for the request.

Comment: Change Handler to lowercase. Might be it.

Comment: ie. change the whole url to lowercase. The redirect is from `"/Handlers/Handler.ashx"` to  `"/handlers/handler.ashx"`. Maybe there's an urlrewrite in the web.config that enforces lowercase urls and does a redirect otherwise?

Comment: I changed it to lower case and the redirect is solved, but it didn't solve the issue of the params

Comment: Is context.Request.Form.AllKeys still empty? Try and access via context.Request.Form["op"] instead.

Comment: I've tried it as well, the `context.Request.Form.AllKeys` is empty and `context.Request.Form["op"]` is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113838/discussion-between-elwin-arens-and-liran-friedman).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the data like:

```
  data: '{"op":"register_to_newsletter","name":"' + name.val() + '","email" :"' + email.val() + '"}'
```

And also use:

```
context.Request.Form["op"];
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you start working with proper data models?

Instead of using HTTPContext, make your input parameter a model of the data that you want to receive. Then you won't have any issues.

Comment: Care to give a sample ?

Answer (score -1):

Stringify your object before sending, like this

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        "op": "register_to_newsletter",
        "name": name.val(),
        "email": email.val()
    }),
```

So the full code should be like this

```
var name = $("#txtNewsletterName");
var email = $("#txtNewsletterEmail");

$.ajax({
    url: "/Handlers/Handler.ashx",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "op": "register_to_newsletter",
        "name": name.val(),
        "email": email.val()
    }),
    async: true
});
```