# Redirect use and POST params

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to implement this example with Spring:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/redirect/to_payment/{token}")
public ModelAndView handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token,
        @RequestBody Transaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.someserver.com";
    String post_token = "1234561234543322";

    // Open here the link and redirect the

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url); 
}
```

How I can open this link, sent the post_token as POST param and return the opened page to the user?

Is there some way to implement this solution for the user? 
As the second solution can I return this page to the user and include the `post_token` as a param?

Comment: @MartenCatcher nah, he want to proxy the call.

Comment: Use a RestTemplate

Comment: @ThomasAndolf can you show me code example please?

Comment: Google how to use a resttemplate, there are about a million examples out there. Then try to implement a solution yourself. If you get stuck post how far you have gotten and specific questions. Im not going to write your code.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: Redirect should be used to redirect to another route within your controllers, not to redirect to an entirely different website, and additionally, it won't fetch any data from it.

Comment: @g00glen00b Can you recommend some solution?

Comment: u also can send a http request from server and return the response body to the client

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan Can you show me code example please?

Comment: where should u send ur token to that url? in header or as an path param? say that so I can right an example

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan into the header.

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735/7458887

Comment: You have to be a bit more precise.
For just calling another url, you can use the restTemplate in spring. Here you can define the target url , header params ( where I guess you want to put your token to) and so on. 
If you completely want to redirect to another resource, have a look at "CORS" [prinzip][1]. Do you own the the resource under the url ? 


  [1]: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Do you use a template engine or is this just REST?

Comment: it's just REST. Can you elaborate a bit more what do you mean?

Comment: Is post_token not to be shared on client side? If it can be shared, we can redirect client.

Comment: Can you show me both solutions please?

Comment: my solution didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use okhttp3 dependency and send an http request from server and then return the response body of okhttp object to the client.

Here is an example:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/redirect/to_payment/{token}")
  public ModelAndView handleRedirectMessage(@PathVariable("token") String token,
          @RequestBody Transaction transaction, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.someserver.com";
    String post_token = "1234561234543322";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .url(url)
         .post(null) // because u have no body
         .addHeader("Authorization", post_token)
         .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
         .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    return new ModelAndView(response.body().toString()); // or something like this
}
```

Of course you have to handle `IOException` and the body method at the end may be a little different.

One tip: you can use postman to generate OkHttp or Unirest request code for you by simulating your request easily.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to actually do the post request to external server (eg. Using Apache HttpClient or for simple cases JSoup) and return response body to original caller.

If you want to perform a kind of eg login on behalf of user, you would also have to perform controlled session hijack.

Answer (score 0):

To ask to redirect a user's browser, you need to send JS code  and on page load event, you have to call redirect code like this

```
function redirectPost(url, data) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.method = 'post';
    form.action = url;
    for (var name in data) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = name;
        input.value = data[name];
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    form.submit();
}
// call on window load
 redirectPost('http://www.someserver.com', { post_token: '1234561234543322' });
```