# How to redirect to a post upon authentication in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

Maybe I am trying to do something stupid but...

I am attempting to build a ServiceStack OAuth Provide for Azure AD.  The redirect URI is passed through by the SS Authentication but I am not sure what to do when the initiating request is a POST rather than a GET.  The final redirect is always a GET and I cannot work out how to preserve the initial form data.

Amy I trying to do something reasonable?  Any clues on where I should look to preserve my sanity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [can't redirect to a POST reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735/85785), one solution is to [return HTML that auto submits a FORM POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802848/85785):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>",postbackUrl);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{0}'>", id);
// Other params go here
sb.Append("</form>");
sb.Append("</body>");
sb.Append("</html>");
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort to actually write the code, I think I was running at 50% yesterday.