# .Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages : autoredirect to culture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I try to accomplish a similar behaviour with MS Docs.

For example, if you visit *https://learn.microsoft.com/*, you will be redirected to your culture, in my case I'm being redirected automatically to *https://learn.microsoft.com/**en-gb**/*.

Same goes for inner pages if you access them without the culture in the URL.

For instance, by accessing:

*https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio*

it will be automatically redirect you to:

*https://learn.microsoft.com/**en-gb**/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio*

I have a small demo app where I conduct my localisation experiment for .NET Core 3.1 and Razor Pages [here](https://github.com/panosru/.net-rnd-i18n).

I have set `options.Conventions` [here](https://github.com/panosru/.net-rnd-i18n/blob/52768062f4e5e5a8b749e760d0cce95d04b8a0c3/Startup.cs#L37), and I have created `CustomCultureRouteRouteModelConvention` class [here](https://github.com/panosru/.net-rnd-i18n/blob/master/Localization/CustomCultureRouteRouteModelConvention.cs), but I'm fairly novice with .NET Core and I'm kind of stuck on how to implement the above-described functionality.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use existing Rewriting Middleware to do redirects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1
In the simplest form, you can tell rewrite middleware to redirect if it does not see a locale pattern at the beginning of the URL path, maybe

`new RewriteOptions() .AddRedirect("^([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})", "en-US/$1")`

(regex not tested) or do full redirect class with more detailed rules when and to what locale you want to redirect. Example in that aspnet document references [RedirectImageRequest](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/ad16f5e1da6c04fa4996ee67b513f2a90fa0d712/aspnetcore/fundamentals/url-rewriting/samples/2.x/SampleApp/RewriteRules.cs) which you can use to get an understanding of how custom redirect rules works. Adapting to your case as a proof of concept, I reused most of the logic in your existing `RedirectUnsupportedCulture`:

```
public class RedirectUnsupportedCultures : IRule
    {
        private readonly string _extension;
        private readonly PathString _newPath;
        private IList<CultureInfo> _cultureItems;
        private string _cultureRouteKey;

        public RedirectUnsupportedCultures(IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> options)
        {
            RouteDataRequestCultureProvider provider = options.Value.RequestCultureProviders
                .OfType<RouteDataRequestCultureProvider>()
                .First();

            _cultureItems = options.Value.SupportedUICultures;

            _cultureRouteKey = provider.RouteDataStringKey;
        }

        public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext rewriteContext)
        {
            // do not redirect static assets and do not redirect from a controller that is meant to set the locale
            // similar to how you would not restrict a guest user from login form on public site.
            if (rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".ico") ||
                rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("change-culture"))
            {
                return;
            }

            IRequestCultureFeature cultureFeature = rewriteContext.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
            string actualCulture = cultureFeature?.RequestCulture.Culture.Name;
            string requestedCulture = rewriteContext.HttpContext.GetRouteValue(_cultureRouteKey)?.ToString();

            // Here you can add more rules to redirect based on maybe cookie setting, or even language options saved in database user profile
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedCulture) || _cultureItems.All(x => x.Name != requestedCulture)
                && !string.Equals(requestedCulture, actualCulture, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                string localizedPath = $"/{actualCulture}{rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}";

                HttpResponse response = rewriteContext.HttpContext.Response;
                response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
                rewriteContext.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;

                // preserve query part parameters of the URL (?parameters) if there were any
                response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] =
                    localizedPath + rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            }
        }
```

and registered it in `Startup.cs` with

```
// Attempt to make auto-redirect to culture if it is not exist in the url
RewriteOptions rewriter = new RewriteOptions();
rewriter.Add(new RedirectUnsupportedCultures(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>()));
app.UseRewriter(rewriter);
```

#### Improvement:

After using the above code I bumped on a bug that in case the culture is not supported by the application, the redirection will end up with infinite culture paths. For example, if I support the cultures `en` (default) and `gr`, if instead of either `/en/foobar` or `/gr/foobar` I would write `/fr/foobar`, I would end up getting `/en/fr/foobar` then `/en/en/fr/foobar` and etc.

I added `private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;` to the class, which I initialise it in the constructor. I removed that line `string localizedPath = $"/{actualCulture}{rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value}";` and the code after that line looks like this:

```cs
rewriteContext.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values[_cultureRouteKey] = actualCulture;

HttpResponse response = rewriteContext.HttpContext.Response;
response.StatusCode   = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
rewriteContext.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;

// preserve query part parameters of the URL (?parameters) if there were any
response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] =
    _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
        rewriteContext.HttpContext,
        values: rewriteContext.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values
    )
  + rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
```

Comment: Thank very much for the response @alex-tech! That indeed is what I was looking for :)

Comment: @alex-tech ... Thanks for the method. Just one question though.. In case our intial request was a POST, is it possible to persist that in our rewrite location...

Suppose I have a URL /search, it is converting it to /en/search, but if the /search was a POST request, the /en/search becomes a GET in the subsequent hit...

Comment: @StackAddict take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get

Comment: @panosru Your improvement actually works as intended however it has an issue, if you are going for a real URL like localhost/about, it will automatically redirect to homepage at localhost/en

Comment: One more thing, I recommend changing the status code to Status308PermanentRedirect for it to support post methods from page to another.

Comment: Thanks, @Muhab for pointing those out! It's been a while and I have made some updates already, I think the issue you are mentioning is fixed (https://github.com/panosru/CleanDDDArchitecture/tree/master/Hosts/WebApp/Core/Localisation), I do agree with the 308 suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As decribed in Microsoft docs [localization middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#localization-middleware); each the localization request initializes a list of `RequestCultureProvider` and is **enumerated by the below order** :

1. [`QueryStringRequestCultureProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#querystringrequestcultureprovider) : e.g. `http://localhost:1234/Index?culture=en`
2. [`CookieRequestCultureProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookierequestcultureprovider) : Looks for the culture cookie, and it will be null if you haven't set it manually.
3. [`AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-accept-language-http-header) : This one depends on the browsers cultures adn this is what you need to look for.

To make sure how it works, delete the culture cookie and change the browser language preferences by moving the desired language to the top, you will see that the language is selected according to the browser preferences.

Comment: thank you for your response, my issue is not detecting the locale but how to properly redirect the user as I describe in my post. For example, if you check my demo app, I have two cultures, one is en-US and the other is en-GB. When visiting https://localhost:5001, when on en-US locale you will see "Welcome friend!" message, and when on en-GB you will see "Welcome lad!". What I'm trying is when visiting to automatically redirect to /{locale}. Also if you visit /about to automatically redirect to /{locale}/about etc... I'm kind of struggling with this since my fairly new to .net world

Comment: I already checked your app, it is working as expected. Just do not set the culture cookie, and it will use browser local by default.

Comment: Yes, by removing the cookie it detects the browser locale, that I know, but it does not automatically redirect, it does on your end? You visit https://localhost:5001/ and it automatically redirects you to https://localhost:5001/en-US for example?