# Can we make a POST request without expecting a response back

Tags: javascript, httprequest

Which request method I should use here:- I want to send some credentials in the body because of confidentiality but at the same time, I am not expecting anything in response instead I am expecting a redirect.

Comment: Looks like you want to do a temporary redirect, http status code 303. See  [Redirections in HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)

Comment: Thanks @marcusholmgren for responding but I want to send credentials in body i.e POST request and expecting a GET request instead of a response. Could this be possible?.

Comment: you can listen to the post request's response and if it was successful, you can then send the get request .

Comment: Thanks, @Hossein Yes this is the last option I can think but could you please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098129/can-a-post-request-be-redirected-as-another-get-request. This is the actual scenario. Can you please comment about would that even possible?

Comment: @Hossein I wanted to redirect from the server-side due to some reasons

Comment: so I guess the temp redirect is what you need. you send a post request and the server will redirect you to another URL

Comment: can we change the request method after temporary redirect on server side? ...i.e from POST to GET