# ASP.NET (C#) do a post to page from code and go to that page

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I am very new to .NET and am now in need to modify an existing ASP.NET website done with C# long back by someone else (with .NET version 2.0).

There are lot of process involved in this website and I need to get few data from the database and then do a POST to another page from the code itself.  I am able to do a redirection to required page with necessary parameters, but need to implement the same with POST.

Can anyone please guide me on how to implement this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few more searches on my requirement, came across another Stackoverflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802848/2451196.

This was a much straight forward approach for me and it worked like a charm.  Thanks to Pavlo Neiman (https://stackoverflow.com/users/164001/pavlo-neiman)

Comment: Just remove this question in that case... it will shortly be closed anyhow.